# How to add a class to selected date in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery date picker plugin for date ranges. I have 2 date fields from and to fields. I want to add a class to the selected from date field so that when I switch to 'To' field I can see the from date selected and styled differently using that new class added.

I've got this working if the from and to dates are selected for different months. But if both dates are in same month then there is no class and I can't find a way for it.

For different months there is a class ui-datepicker-days-cell-over which I've used. But in case of same month there is no class.

I've also tried OnSelect and beforeShowDay function but to no help.I am using jQuery picker with Drupal.

Here is the screenshot for different months and same month:

[image: Image for different months]

[image: Image for same month]

[The snippet for what I have tried](http://jsfiddle.net/0n3o38nd/)

```js
$(function() {
  var day = new Date().getDate();
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
       onSelect: function(selectedDate, el) {
    // custom callback logic here
    console.log(el);
                 
   },
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {   
      console.log(date.getDate); 
       if (date.getDate() == day) {
                return [true, "selected", ""]; // Here you set your css class
            } else {
                return [true, ""]
            }     
        // set all the dates to have reserved class for now 
        
     },
     
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1d",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-current-day  { color:white;background:red;)
    .ui-datepicker-days-cell-over{background-color: #e0001b!important;color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Comment: you have the class " ui-datepicker-current-day", you can use it, but know that the datepicker is building itself again (so each class you add will be erased). You can trigger your event with setTimeout to after the datepicker rebuilt itself. Hope it helps.

Comment: It removes the class when I move to second datepicker and different month. How to stop the fdatepicker to build itself.